# Question on Morse and Feshbach's book

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I am interested in moving into the fields of mathematical physics and applied mathematics, and wish to build a solid background over the coming years. My background is a PhD in electromagnetic engineering.

After some research, it seems that the famous book by Morse and Feshbach, 'Methods of Theoretical Physics', is highly and repeatedly cited as a key reference. So, is this a good compendium of the subject that can build a solid background in this field? Are there any other contenders which are as well-regarded and as comprehensive?

Does the book by Arfken (et. al.), 'Mathematical Methods for Physicists', or the book by Jeffreys and Jefferys, 'Methods of Mathematical Physics', compare to Morse and Feshbach?

Any comments on how they compare (level, depth, scope, assumptions of reader background, etc), or suggestions of others, would be appreciated.

Finally, some people suggest that I should first do a course in Analysis, such as using the book of Whittaker and Watson, 'A Course of Modern Analysis'. Is this necessary or can one go staight to the above references?

Comment: Morse and Feshback is a huge compendium, very well written but a little "oldish" in some of its approaches, with some lackings on modern tools ; it can be advised now more as a reference than as a treatise you must read from cover to cover. Arfken is a good compromise. "Whittaker and Watson", magnificently written book but I would classify it as the one by Morse and Feshbach, "oldish". I would advise Landau Lifschitz course on mechanics. See also Hasanni "Mathematical Physics".

Comment: @JeanMarie Many thanks for this. Any advice about whether i need to do a course in Analysis, say like that in Whittaker and Watson, before delving into mathematical physics books like Hassani or others?

Comment: [Whittaker & Watson](https://archive.org/details/cu31924001549660) is online.